# An internal error for view and edit view in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, fullcalendar

I follow a tutorial to add Full Calendar to my application . With the controller EventTypes, the index and the add view works , i've no problem .

For the view and edit view i get an error :

An Internal Error Has Occurred

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

I'm using Cakephp 2 and PHP 5.4 .

This my controller :

```
<?php

class EventTypesController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'EventTypes';

        var $paginate = array(
            'limit' => 15
        );

    public function admin_index() {
        $this->EventType->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('eventTypes', $this->paginate());
    }

    public function admin_view($id = null) {
        if(!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid event type', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->set('eventType', $this->EventType->read(null, $id));
    }

    public function admin_add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            $this->EventType->create();
            if ($this->EventType->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event type has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event type could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
    }

    public function admin_edit($id = null) {
        if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid event type', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->EventType->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event type has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event type could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $this->EventType->read(null, $id);
        }
    }

    public function admin_delete($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for event type', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        if ($this->EventType->delete($id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Event type deleted', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Event type was not deleted', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
?>
```

My model :

```
<?php
class EventType extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'EventType';
    var $displayField = 'name';
    var $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
            ),
        ),
    );

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Event' => array(
            'className' => 'FullCalendar.Event',
            'foreignKey' => 'event_type_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        )
    );

}
?>
```

Comment: enable debug mode. What is the error from the log?

Comment: Error: The application is trying to load a file from the FullCalendar plugin, i guess in my model the script call the plugin, i don't know where . i will edit my post and put my model .

Comment: I don't want to have a folder "plugin" .

Comment: The error is being caused because in your `app/Plugin` directory you should have a `FullCalendar` folder. To correct this you should put the `FullCalendar` plugin folder in `app/Plugin` so Cake is able to find it